# Почему MSSQL называют SQL Server'ом?

Tags: sql, sql-server, сервер

Почему MSSQL называют SQL Server'ом или MS SQL Server?

Другие языки запросов же тоже с сервером работают.

(Гугл/Яндекс не дал ответов)

Comment: а почему гугл называют гуглом, а яндекс яндексом?

Comment: Ну майкрософтовский язык запросов это T-SQL.
Получается MSSQL - это альтернативное называние SQL Managment Studio?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий

Comment: _"MS SQL Server"_ это название семейства продуктов, _Managment studio_ одна из его составляющих - клиентская среда написания запросов и т.п. а _"T-SQL"_ это название так сказать "диалекта"

Answer (score 3):

[Вот что находит Google если копнуть чуть глубже поверхностного поиска](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/euanga/2006/01/19/sql-mythbusters-sql-server-is-really-a-sybase-product-not-a-microsoft-one/):

> At the time the leader in the “PC” database systems (non
>   mainframe/mini/UNIX) was a product from "Ashton Tate" called `dBase` (my
>   first database app was written using dBase III+ on DOS 3.3). To help
>   leverage the large dBase installed base and to give Ashton Tate a true
>   Client Server offering, Microsoft and Ashton Tate with help from
>   Sybase announced `Ashton-Tate/Microsoft SQL Server` (Sybase later
>   renamed their product to `Sybase SQL Server for UNIX and VMS`), this was
>   to be the name of the OS/2 port of `Sybase DataServer`.
>
> V1 of Ashton-Tate/Microsoft SQL Server was shipped in 1989. Originally
>   dBase IV was supposed to have provided a dev tool/front end for SQL
>   Server (hence the original partnership) but the problems with dBase IV
>   after its release later in the year led to this falling by the
>   wayside. At this point the partnership between Microsoft and Ashton
>   Tate was dissolved and the product became `Microsoft SQL Server` (there
>   are still a few members of the dev team that were around in the
>   original days and proudly have their `Ashton-Tate/Microsoft SQL Server`
>   boxes in their offices).